# How i can convert string to json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

'"{\"result\":{\"additionalDetails\":\"Additional details go here.\",\"addressLine1\":\"123 Test St\",\"addressLine2\":null,\"addressLine3\":null,\"addressLine4\":null,\"bedrooms\":3,\"cancelled\":null,\"competingCompanies\":0,\"county\":\"Test County\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-08-20 15:57:44\",\"customerName\":\"Test Customer\",\"email\":\"test@email.com\",\"houseType\":\"detached\",\"phone\":\"00000111111\",\"postcode\":\"CF11 9HB\",\"price\":233000,\"propertyType\":\"house\",\"quoteId\":\"Tes-1597935464\",\"surveyType\":\"Building\",\"town\":\"Test Town\"},\"timestamp\":1597935464,\"token\":\"c48753bc28e1b53b05eac8164356eeef2ee4ada1aa47df69ed\",\"signature\":\"e213b10fff881becdc41cd81f4275385034ac60f7dbf2c1d370c937ab7b29ae2\"}"'

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Note that you'll need to provide that function with valid JSON though, which your example is not - you need to remove the ```\\``` characters

Comment: can you please try to write a question, add what you have, what you want and take a look at [tour] to learn [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to do some pre-replace in your string before parse it as JSON, obviously

```js
const str = '"{\"result\":{\"additionalDetails\":\"Additional details go here.\",\"addressLine1\":\"123 Test St\",\"addressLine2\":null,\"addressLine3\":null,\"addressLine4\":null,\"bedrooms\":3,\"cancelled\":null,\"competingCompanies\":0,\"county\":\"Test County\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-08-20 15:57:44\",\"customerName\":\"Test Customer\",\"email\":\"test@email.com\",\"houseType\":\"detached\",\"phone\":\"00000111111\",\"postcode\":\"CF11 9HB\",\"price\":233000,\"propertyType\":\"house\",\"quoteId\":\"Tes-1597935464\",\"surveyType\":\"Building\",\"town\":\"Test Town\"},\"timestamp\":1597935464,\"token\":\"c48753bc28e1b53b05eac8164356eeef2ee4ada1aa47df69ed\",\"signature\":\"e213b10fff881becdc41cd81f4275385034ac60f7dbf2c1d370c937ab7b29ae2\"}"';

// First trim " symbols at the beginning
// and at the end then parse as JSON
const res = JSON.parse(str.replace(/^\"(.*)\"$/, '$1'));

// Log
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Veera this is what you need?

Answer (score -1):

i think you can use JSON.parse() function

```
const text = "{\"result\":{\"additionalDetails\":\"Additional details go here.\",\"addressLine1\":\"123 Test St\",\"addressLine2\":null,\"addressLine3\":null,\"addressLine4\":null,\"bedrooms\":3,\"cancelled\":null,\"competingCompanies\":0,\"county\":\"Test County\",\"createdAt\":\"2020-08-20 15:57:44\",\"customerName\":\"Test Customer\",\"email\":\"test@email.com\",\"houseType\":\"detached\",\"phone\":\"00000111111\",\"postcode\":\"CF11 9HB\",\"price\":233000,\"propertyType\":\"house\",\"quoteId\":\"Tes-1597935464\",\"surveyType\":\"Building\",\"town\":\"Test Town\"},\"timestamp\":1597935464,\"token\":\"c48753bc28e1b53b05eac8164356eeef2ee4ada1aa47df69ed\",\"signature\":\"e213b10fff881becdc41cd81f4275385034ac60f7dbf2c1d370c937ab7b29ae2\"}"

const json =JSON.parse(text)
console.log(json)
// {
//   "result": {
//     "additionalDetails": "Additional details go here.",
//     "addressLine1": "123 Test St",
//     "addressLine2": null,
//     "addressLine3": null,
//     "addressLine4": null,
//     "bedrooms": 3,
//     "cancelled": null,
//     "competingCompanies": 0,
//     "county": "Test County",
//     "createdAt": "2020-08-20 15:57:44",
//     "customerName": "Test Customer",
//     "email": "test@email.com",
//     "houseType": "detached",
//     "phone": "00000111111",
//     "postcode": "CF11 9HB",
//     "price": 233000,
//     "propertyType": "house",
//     "quoteId": "Tes-1597935464",
//     "surveyType": "Building",
//     "town": "Test Town"
//   },
//   "timestamp": 1597935464,
//   "token": "c48753bc28e1b53b05eac8164356eeef2ee4ada1aa47df69ed",
//   "signature": "e213b10fff881becdc41cd81f4275385034ac60f7dbf2c1d370c937ab7b29ae2"
// }
```

Comment: in the example on the question you put a "," at end of the string. So if remove that "," the string inside "{}" is properly formatted. i tried with that string and i get a valid result. if u can explain the error that u getting. please

Comment: if u gettin a string for some reason and want to remove you can do string.replace(/"/g ,"") but im triying to get the same behaivor and i cant